# Why nil:NilClass error when trying to access this self.attribute within model.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I am trying to write my own validation for a `date_of_birth` attr on an `Employee` model and I fail to see what I am getting wrong, I'm sure it's something really daft and right under my nose. The code is as below and my error message is;

```
 NoMethodError:
    undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass
```

employee.rb

```
  class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :quote

    validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :email, :gender, :date_of_birth, :salary
    validates :first_name, length: { minimum: 2, message: "minimum of 2 chars" }
    validates :last_name, length: { minimum: 2, message: "minimum of 2 chars" }
    validates_email_format_of :email, :message => 'incorrect email format'
    validate :older_than_16

    enum gender: [ :m, :f ]

    private

    def older_than_16
        self.date_of_birth < Time.now-16.years
    end

end
```

schema.rb

```
   ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170620125346) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "employees", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "initial"
    t.integer  "gender"
    t.date     "date_of_birth"
    t.integer  "salary"
    t.integer  "quote_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
    t.index ["quote_id"], name: "index_employees_on_quote_id", using: :btree
  end
```

employee_spec.rb

```
RSpec.describe Employee, type: :model do
    describe 'validations' do   

        it { should validate_presence_of(:date_of_birth) }
        it { should_not allow_value(Date.today-15.years).for(:date_of_birth) }
        # it { should allow_value(Date.today-17.years).for(:date_of_birth) }
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your custom method matcher is called even for the first test but `self.date_of_birth` is actually `nil` so you see this error.
You have to check if the `date_of_birth` is not `nil` before compare it.
You also have to [add a new entry](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods) to the `errors` collection if you consider your model invalid.
(Also check your condition, I use `>` instead of `<` to make your test pass)

```
  def older_than_16
      return if self.date_of_birth.nil?
      if self.date_of_birth > Time.now-16.years
          errors.add(:date_of_birth, "Should be at least 16 years old")
      end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks @ Aschen, that works perfectly now. But I do not understand how `self.date_of_birth` was ever nil though? Presence was validated and passed tests? How was it nil? Thanks for helping me here 

Comment: I do not know how `should-matcher` work internally but I think that `it { should validate_presence_of(:date_of_birth) }` try to check the presence validation by passing a `nil` value and except that the model will return false for `model.valid?`